# Angular 4 - Multiple instances of modules in memory

Tags: angular

We have a large `Angular 4` application using `lazy loading` along with the preloading strategy of `preloadAllModules`. We are using `Angular CLI`.

While looking at a memory issue in the Chrome inspector, I noticed that we have multiple module instances everywhere.

[image]

If I am reading this right, we have 83 instances of `TranslateModule` and `HttpModule` etc...

Only thing I can think of is that every `lazy loaded` module has its own root which needs to create its own module for that bundle?

Is it possible to get rid of all these instances or is that just how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to get rid of all these instances or is that just how
>   it works?

Yes, just import them into root `AppModule`. However, while you can avoid putting `HttModule` into every loaded module and can import it only once into root `AppModule`, you can't avoid duplication for `RouterModule` which should be used like this `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`.

The duplication happens because every lazy loaded module has its own injector with its own instances of all imported modules. So if you have 83 lazy-loaded modules and each module imports `HttpModule` and `RouterModule` you will have 83 instances of each imported module.

For more information read here:

- [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: I added my shared modules and components to a SharedModule and even though I import that into my AppModule, I'm still required to import the SharedModule into my lazy loaded module. Without it, the compiler can't find the proper definitions. Does importing this twice duplicate instances of the code? Is my SharedModule cached?

Answer (score 2):

You should put all of these shared modules into a core module which is only ever loaded once and only imported by the app module

Comment: `RouterModule` should be imported in each lazy loaded module, you can't avoid that

Comment: the routermodule is a different case, each module needs it's own. I meant cases where modules don't need their own, and they can use a shared instance.

Comment: yes, so he can't avoid having 83 instances and that's by design

Comment: he can avoid 83 instances of the http module and the translate module... quite easily. just because he can't eliminate all duplication doesn't mean he shouldnt eliminate it where he can.