# How many instances of a module end up in the final bundle if it's referenced by several modules?

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-lazyloading

I'm wondering what's the best strategy between

- a shared module that contains all the reusable code
- individual reusable codes that are referenced when needed

I suppose that the case against putting all the reusable codes in a shared module is that it will be huge  and will slow down the loading of the application because not every module need all the code in the share module.

Both `GalleryModule` and `ProfileModule` import `CardModule`. They are both lazy loaded as well.

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...,
        CardModule, 
        ...
    ]
})
export class GalleryModule { }

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...,
        CardModule, 
        ...
    ]
})
export class ProfileModule { }
```

Let's say the user visits the **gallery page**. The **galleryModule** will be loaded along with **its dependency**, i.e. the **CardModule**. Let's say, after that, the user decides to go to the **profile page**, which will result in the **ProfileModule** being loaded.

Will the **CardModule** be loaded for the **second time** or will Angular just reuse the **CardModule** that was loaded along with **GallelryModule**?

## Edit

It seems like someone else asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006202/creating-shared-module-across-lazy-loaded-routes?rq=1). However, it doesn't seem like anybody responded clearly to the question.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think it is very possible you've conflated two different topics. In the title you ask about what ends up in the final bundle, while in the question, you ask about lazy-loading modules. You can't have it both ways. The final bundle _only_ includes those modules that are eagerly loaded. All lazy loaded modules are excluded from that bundle. Reference: [DON'T EAGERLY IMPORT SOMETHING FROM A LAZY-LOADED MODULE](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#lazy-loading) (caps are from the header on the page - not here to scream at you :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `CardModule` will not be loaded for the second time. Angular has its internal mechanism to detect if a module is already loaded. If so, it doesn't load the module again, and uses the already loaded instance.

Note that lazy modules are ***not*** put in the *final bundle*, they are loaded only when the corresponding lazy route is accessed.

At development time, following is what you'll see after running your application with `CLI 11.x` -

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files       | Names                  |      Size
vendor.js                 | vendor                 |   7.52 MB
polyfills.js              | polyfills              | 484.59 kB
styles.css, styles.js     | styles                 | 419.34 kB
main.js                   | main                   |  79.30 kB
runtime.js                | runtime                |   9.08 kB

                          | Initial Total          |   8.49 MB

Lazy Chunk Files          | Names                  |      Size
gallery-gallery-module.js | gallery-gallery-module |   7.36 kB
profile-profile-module.js | profile-profile-module |   7.35 kB
common.js
```

and following are some information on how the loading works -

1. the `Initial Chunk Files` comprise the final bundle and `main.js` is where all your eager modules (app module, shared module, etc) are put.
2. the `Lazy Chunk Files` comprise the list of lazy modules that Angular keeps, and the `CardModule` is put in `common.js`.
3. if you access the `profile page`, the `profile-profile-module.js` and `common.js` are loaded. When you access the `gallery page` later, only `gallery-gallery-module.js` is loaded. You can check this on your browser's Network tab when you access the lazy routes.
4. if you had other modules which are used by multiple lazy modules, those too would be put in the `common.js`.
5. if you had modules which are used only by a single lazy module, then those would be bundled with that lazy module rather than putting them in the `common.js`. For example, if you had an `XyzModule` module that is used only by the `GalleryModule`, then it would be bundled with the `GalleryModule` and put in the `gallery-gallery-module.js`.

**EDIT:**
You can use the `ng build` command and check the generated physical files listed above in the `dist` directory to get a better picture of which modules get bundled with which.

Comment: I suppose the decision put a dependent module either in the common.js or bundle it with lazy-loaded module is made during the compilation process.

Comment: @Richard77 "During the Build process" would be more appropriate, I think.

Comment: Yes. during the build process.